# How can I update or delete all item at once in the JSP page?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have the following cart form like this
[image: Here is the following webform]

and this is the source code for this form

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">  
        <title>ROOM SERVICE ORDER SYSTEM</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../WEB-INF/css/jquery.mobile.structure-        1.0.1.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../WEB-INF/css/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../WEB-INF/css/style.css" />
        <script src="../WEB-INF/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../WEB-INF/js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <!--------------page displayed in the browser---------------->
        <div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="c">
            <div data-role="content">
                <form action="orderServlet" method="POST">
                    <div data-role="header">
                        <div id="title">
                            <h3>ROOM SERVICE </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div id="menu">
                            <div style="float: left;width:10px;height: 1px;">
                                <a href="../index.jsp"><img src="../js/images/arrow.png" alt=""/></a>
                            </div>
                            <h3>CART</h3>
                        </div>           
                    </div>
                    <!-----class adds extra padding and margin inside the page content------>
                    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                        <div id ="center_sub">
                            <table>
                                <!---------------------------------------------------->  
                                <tr  id ="trsub">
                                    <td id="tdsub_item">Item</td>
                                    <td id="tdsub_price">Price</td>
                                    <td id="tdtitle_qty">Qty</td>
                                    <td id="tdtitle_delete">Delete</td>
                                </tr>
                                <c:forEach var = "orderitem" items = "${order.orderdetails}">
                                    <tr id="trsub">
                                        <td id="tdsub_item">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="item" value="${orderitem.item.itemid}" />
                                            <c:out value="${orderitem.item.itemname}"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td id="tdsub_price">
                                            <c:out value="${orderitem.item.itemprice}"/>
                                        </td>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="item" value="${orderitem.item.tax}" />

                                    <td id="tdsub_qty">
                                        <select name ="select" >
                                            <option value="1">1</option>
                                            <option value="2">2</option>
                                            <option value="3">3</option>
                                        </select>  
                                    </td>
                                    <!---------Check box Delete----------->
                                    <td id="tdsub_delete">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="Delete" value="">  
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </c:forEach>
                                <!---------------------------------------------------->  
                            </table> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!----- End of class adds extra padding and margin inside the page content------>

                    <!--------- button cear cart and update cart----------->
                    <div id="wrapp-button">
                        <!------------ button Clear Cart--------------->
                        <div class="button-clear">
                            <input type="button" name="Clear" value="Clear Cart">
                        </div>
                        <!-------------------------------------------->

                        <!-------------button Update Cart-------------->
                        <div class="button-update">
                            <input type="submit" name ="Update" value="Update Cart">
                        </div>
                        <!----------------------------------------------->
                    </div>
                    <!----------------------------------------------------------->
                    <div style="width:100%;padding-top: 15px;">
                        <table style="border: 1px solid #4596ce;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width:85%;">Subtotal</td>
                                <td style="width:15%;">12</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width:85%;">In room delivery charge (fixed)</td>
                                <td style="width:15%;">$1.10</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width:85%;color: #000000;">Total</td>
                                <td style="width:15%;"><c:out value=""/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width:100%;">(Tax included in above TOTAL: 10%)</td>
                                <td style="width:100%;">$4.30</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>    
                    </div>
                    <!---------Button Proceed to Order--------->
                    <div id="footer_sub">
                        <input type="submit" name="Proceed" value="Proceed to Order">
                    </div>
                    <!------------------------------------------>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

how to specific the item in reach rows when we click on the update cart, so it will only update the item according to the parameters that we send from the web which should be specific by the id but I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone point out how to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this approch you can just pass `itemid` as value to checkbox so when you submit the form only those values will be set which you have selected and then you can get those values into a string array using `request.getParameterValues()` and then check in the order list whether this item is present or not, if present then remove that item from list :

```html
<!---------Check box Delete----------->
<td id="tdsub_delete">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Delete" value="${orderitem.item.itemid}">  
</td>
```

And in servlet

```
String[] items = request.getParameterValues("Delete");    
//assuming Order is your order class and orderList is your item list    
for(Order order : orderList)
{
    for(String str : items)
    {
        if(str.equals(order.getItemID()))
        {
            //logic to remove item from list
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know how to do that but I want it to work the way it is now because the design flow is to work that way, so I cannot change the way of implementation or re-designing the JSP.

Comment: checkout the answer from existing way.